# Inventory sync between Magento and Shopify Stores

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, shopify, inventory-management

I have 3 stores: Magento USA (USD), [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) (Germany) (EUR), and [Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps)  (UK) (GBP).

I need to link the products and sync inventory between all 3 stores, and make sure its always the same.

What would be the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a one only solution. You can, either set up a [Shopify PLUS](https://www.shopify.com/plus?ref=microapps) store where you'll be able to manage multiple stores while having stocs synced, or you could take a look at the [Shopify Webhooks](https://docs.shopify.com/api/webhook/?ref=microapps) for either orders or products in order to remove units once an order hits your Shopify store. You'll need to make sure you have a tool to sync stocks once you update the inventory manually when having new units enter your warehouse.

On a more "global" concept, I'd advise to find any solution which involves managing one only source inventory, otherwise, even if your system is cristal good, there's always the chance where 2 machines stop speaking to each other and the inventory sync mess shows up.